# Equation with prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am reading a paper which, in order to prove a result about graphs, states that if $p$ is a prime, then $$\frac{1}{2}(p^2-1)(p-1) \approx \frac{1}{2} (p^2-1)^{3/2}.$$
In other words, 
$$\frac{1}{2}(p^2-1)(p-1) = \bigg(\frac{1}{2}-o(1)\bigg)(p^2-1)^{3/2}.$$ 
This is stated without further explanation, but I can't see why it is true. Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Stop playing with prime numbers,you are not a kid anymore xd

Comment: Hey, I am trying to prove the statement in order to construct a $K_{2,2}$ graph, which is a VERY grownup thing to do!!

Comment: It would help to have some additional context here showing what the paper does with the asserted approximation, because both sides are also approximately equal to simply ${1\over2}p^3$ (for large $p$).  My guess is that the expression ${1\over2}(p^2-1)^{3/2}$ gets used to simplify some other expression.

Comment: Well, roughly speaking there is a theorem which states that, given a graph on $n$ vertices, there exists a constant $c$ such that the upper bound for a specific property of the graph is $cn^{3/2}$. What follows is an example of the theorem for $n=(p^2-1)$, in which we try to prove that $c=1/2$. I'm not sure how all this is helpful though...

Comment: It helps explain why the paper would both to state the approximation as they did.  Basically, when you're working with large numbers, the highest power dominates everything else, so all the $-1$'s don't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty}\frac{p-1}{\sqrt{p^2-1}}=\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2-1}}}=\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{p^2}}=1$$

Use this to see where the $o(1)$ comes from. Also, note that I've never used that is $p$ prime.

Comment: Thank you and that's actually a very good point. The proof generally uses the fact that $p$ is a prime, but I guess the assumption is not needed in this specific step. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing by $(p^2-1)$ yields $(p-1) \approx ((p-1)(p+1))^{1/2}$, i.e. $ (p-1)^{1/2} \approx  (p+1)^{1/2}$.